# Saving TreeViewer state before setInput()

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jface, treeviewer

I'm trying to save JFace `TreeViewer` expansion state to refresh it after calling `setInput()` method. I tried `getExpandedElements`, `setExpandedElements`, `getExpandedTreePaths`, `setExpandedTreePaths` methods of `TreeViewer` but it doesn't work.

```
Object[] expandedElements = viewer.getExpandedElements();
TreePath[] expandedTreePaths = viewer.getExpandedTreePaths();
viewer.setInput();
viewer.setExpandedElements(expandedElements);
viewer.setExpandedTreePaths(expandedTreePaths);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that your TreeViewer's content provider provides objects that have their `hashCode` and `equals` methods properly defined. `AbstractTreeViewer` needs to be able to compare the old and new objects to determine their expansion state. If `hashCode` and `equals` aren't provided, it's a simple reference check, which won't work if you've recreated your contents.

Comment: This works, but what was not obvious for me: the code of the question is still needed, together with the good hashCode/equals implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg02450.html), take a look at the late [`ResourceNavigator`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/views/navigator/ResourceNavigator.java.htm#ixzz0U6I2RHCh), from the 
`org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator` package.
("late" because that class is no longer used directly, see the [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/ResourceNavigator)).

[image] (as seen in the [eclipse Java Model](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_int_model.htm))

> It uses a `TreeViewer`, and saves the expanded elements and selected elements, among other state.
>   The model elements are `IResource` objects, which are persisted using the `IPersistableElement`/`IElementFactory` mechanism.
>   The `IPersistableElement` adapter is registered against `IResource` in class `WorkbenchAdapter`, but this could instead be obtained by the model element implementing `IPersistableElement` directly.
>   The corresponding `IElementFactory` is declared in an `elementFactory` extension in `org.eclipse.ui.ide`'s `plugin.xml`.
>
> The restored resources know how to get their own children (and parent), via the tree's content provider, so not all elements of the tree need to be persisted.
>
> A similar approach could be used for saving the viewer's input resource.
>   For `ResourceNavigator`, there's a level of indirection here through its `FrameList`'s current frame, but if you step through it in the debugger, you'll see that it's essentially doing the same thing.

---

Small extract (but the rest of the code save also many other things, including selection)

```
if (frameList.getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
    //save frame, it's not the "home"/workspace frame
    TreeFrame currentFrame = (TreeFrame) frameList.getCurrentFrame();
    IMemento frameMemento = memento.createChild(TAG_CURRENT_FRAME);
    currentFrame.saveState(frameMemento);
} else {
    //save visible expanded elements
    Object JavaDoc expandedElements[] = viewer.getVisibleExpandedElements();
    if (expandedElements.length > 0) {
        IMemento expandedMem = memento.createChild(TAG_EXPANDED);
        for (int i = 0; i < expandedElements.length; i++) {
            if (expandedElements[i] instanceof IResource) {
                IMemento elementMem = expandedMem
                        .createChild(TAG_ELEMENT);
                elementMem.putString(TAG_PATH,
                        ((IResource) expandedElements[i]).getFullPath()
                                .toString());
            }
        }
    }
    [...]
 }
```